# postgres: What is the query 'select * from user' actually doing?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In psql, if one types 'select * from user' you'll get something like the following back:

```
 current_user 
--------------
 postgres
```

What is user in this context?

Comment: `select user;` returns the same result set and doing `select user,* from some_table;` returns an additional column called `current_user` to the result set. So it does behave very strangely to me.

Comment: Although the same behaviour happens with `current_timestamp`. Guess postgres is just very flexible in how you can use functions.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Flexible? Can you use `SELECT user()` ?

Comment: @KenWhite If people haven't answered a question they haven't answered a question. There's nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this context, `user` is a reserved internal Postgres function that represents the current user logged in to the database.

This query can also be written as:

`SELECT user;`

Which should yield the same thing.  Note, if you want to actually reference or create a table named `user` you'll have to use quotes, or fully qualify the schema it lives in.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE "user"
(
  id int2 not null
);
```

will work but:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
  id int2 not null
);
```

Will yield an error.

Here's a reference for other system information functions:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-info.html

Comment: (Curious as I have small knowledge of Postgres:) Is it an internal variable or an internal table?

Comment: The Postgres documentation for `user` [is here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-info.html)

Comment: @ypercube - The docs seem to refer to it as a "system information function", but it behaves much more like a built in variable.  Ie, you don't put `()` after it and it can be altered through the `SET` command.

Comment: @ypercube - Thanks for giving me an excuse to dig through the PG system database to investigate.  If you still require a really, really in-depth technical explanation, I would suggest emailing the PG folks who I've always found incredibly helpful at *pgsql-general* at *postgresql.org*

Answer (score 3):

See the Postgresql Documentation on [system functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-info.html).

Basically "`select * from user`" is one of the Postgresql-specific ways of finding the current user.  It is functionally the same as using the current_user function eg: "`select current_user()`".

Other special functions that can be used as tables in queries include:

```
current_catalog
current_schema
```

Comment: Actually. I don't think there is anything special about those functions (other than not requiring parentheses). `SELECT` is [defined as accepting a function name](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-select.html). e.g. `SELECT * from version();` does work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If You are looking for list of users i should seek in pg_user table;
SELECT * FROM pg_user;

Your Query get all data from result of special function named user. That function returns username of current_user.