# Avoid multiple duplicate records due to JOIN needed for filtering

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, postgresql-9.5

So I have three simple tables

```
create table user (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
);

create table item (
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES user(id),
    key TEXT,
    count INTEGER
);

create table foob (
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES user(id),
    value_f TEXT,
    value_t TEXT
);
```

And I need to fetch all users with matching certain items and foobs:

```
select id, name
from user
left join item on item.user_id = user.id
left join foob on foob.user_id = user.id
where item.key = 'my_key' and foob.value_t = 'vtz'
```

But this results into multiple copies of the same result, due to `item` and/or `foob` having multiple rows referring to the same user. Since I only use the other two tables to filter and don't need to use either in my `select`, I obviously don't need multiple copy results. How can I avoid this?

In my real code I'm also using `json_build_object()` with my `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `GROUP BY "user".id` (because it is its table's primary key, all other column in its table functionally depends on it).

```
select    id, name
from      "user"
left join item on item.user_id = "user".id
left join foob on foob.user_id = "user".id
where     item.key = 'my_key' and foob.value_t = 'vtz'
group by  "user".id
```

BTW I'm not sure if those are the names of your real tables. [Funny things happen if you `select * from user`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010634/postgres-what-is-the-query-select-from-user-actually-doing)

Comment: How is `group by` different from `select distinct` in this context?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen there is not much difference in this context, except you can use `json_build_object()`, because the whole output row doesn't need to be compared. [`DISTINCT ON` might also be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23512013/1499698), but `GROUP BY` is a more standard solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix might be to just `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct id, name
from user
left join item on item.user_id = user.id
left join foob on foob.user_id = user.id
where item.key = 'my_key' and foob.value_t = 'vtz'
```

Another option would be to find matching users in a subquery use that:

```
with cte as (
    select t1.user_id
    from item t1
    inner join foob t2
        on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    where t1.key = 'my_key' and t2.value_t = 'vtz'
)
select u.id, u.name
from user u
where u.id in (select user_id from cte)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for not including it originally, but this doesn't work because I'm actually using `select json_build_object()` and `distinct` doesn't work with it :/

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto *edited 1 hour ago* http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42668847/revisions

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `ROW_NUMBER()` function like

```
select * from (
select id, name, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) as rn
from user
left join item on item.user_id = user.id and item.key = 'my_key'
left join foob on foob.user_id = user.id
and foob.value_t = 'vtz' )xxx
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option whitout `JOIN`:

```
select id, name
from user 
where user_id in (
    select user_id from item where key = 'my_key'
    UNION ALL
    select user_id form foob where value_t = 'vtz'
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be running into a data model issue known as the Chasm trap.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I probably should. This doesn't answer my question, doesn't explain what Chasm trap is and how to avoid it, and it doesn't even bother providing a link to any article about Chasm trap. If this was a comment instead of an answer, you might get an upvote.