# php - fetching associative array of pg_execute() prepared statement returns false

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, prepared-statement

## Context

I'm trying to implement a (hopefully) simple login system using PHP and PostgreSQL.

This is the postgres table containing usernames and hashed passwords.

[image: Picture of Table from phpPgAdmin]

Users are not meant to be able to create new rows in this table so I already hashed the passwords using `password_hash('password', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` and then manually copypasted the value in the table.

Let me know if you think this could pose a problem.

Users can, however, login to an already existing account by inputting the right username and password combination into a login form.

When the login button is pressed I need to retrieve information about the user entered, so that if it matches any user I can then verify the password using `password_verify()`.

## The Problem

When the login button is clicked I run this code:

```php
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=host dbname=dbname user=user password=pwd");
if (!$dbconn) {
    die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
}

// setting the username as it would be provided by the form field
$username = 'Dan';

// maybe unrelated: why do I need to write 'username' instead of username? all of my other queries work without ''
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE 'username' = $1";

$stmt = pg_prepare($dbconn, "", $query);
var_dump($stmt); // gives output "resource(3) of type (pgsql result)", got no clue on how to see what's indside

$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "", array($username));
var_dump($result); // gives output "resource(4) of type (pgsql result)"

$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
var_dump($row); // gives output "bool(false)", indicating that pg_fetch_assoc() failed
```

The main problem would be that pg_fetch_assoc() fails and returns false, however I believe this may also be caused by an incorrect query or by the way I build the statement, hence why I included everything.

### Edit

Forgot to mention that I also tried formulating the query as:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $1";
```

And in this case I get and error saying:
`Warning: pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR: column "username" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $1`.

Comment: `'username' = 'Dan'` is false, therefore the query returns no rows,  pg_fetch_assoc has nothing to fetch and returns false. The query should be `"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $1"`. pg_fetch_assoc returning false does not necessarily mean failure but that there is nothing to fetch.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm thanks a lot for this, I forgot to mention that I first tried running the query like you said.

However, in that case I got an error saying `Warning: pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR: column "username" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $1 `

Comment: If a statement "fails", why not check for that? If there was an incorrect query, you would receive an obvious error - if you checked for it

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, in the webpage I check `if (!$stmt) {$location = '/path/login.php?error=sqlerror';
header('Location: ' . $location);
exit();`
But I need to understand why it fails

Comment: "user" is a reserved keyword in postgresql. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010634/postgres-what-is-the-query-select-from-user-actually-doing

Comment: Try `'SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE username = $1'`

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of this list and it instantly solved my issue!

Comment: @Stefanov.sm thanks, your answer works, I just prefer not using double quotes

Comment: `!$stmt`  is not a proper error check, as you don't check the **cause** of the error. Additionally, that code isn't part of the snippet you've shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Don't Panic's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62922717/php-fetching-associative-array-of-pg-execute-prepared-statement-returns-fals?noredirect=1#comment111274392_62922717) I renamed my `user` table to `utiliser` and everything worked as it should have.

It should also be noted that this could be circumvented by using double quotes on the table name (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10891404/5847641)), however, double quotes are evil so better to just stay away.

[Here's the full table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) of reserved words to avoid as table/column names.